# SQLite supported database formats?

Tags: database, sqlite

was just wondering what formats of databases can SQLite support.

i only know of .sql. Is .mdf supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension doesn't actually matter; only the contents do.  But it supports SQLite databases. :)  MDF is an SQL Server format, and is not supported.

Comment: sorry but where do i find a list of supported SQLIte databases?

Comment: @Kenneth, see http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html and http://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html .  There's really just one evolving database format.